# Laguerre polynomials references

Tags: orthogonal-polynomials

Working on a problem I recently bumped into the family of polynomials

$p_n(x):=n!L_n^{1}(-x)$

where $L_n^{\alpha}(x)$ denotes the classical family of Laguerre (orthogonal) polynomials. In particular, I'm interested in the location of the zeros of $p_n$ (which coincide with the negatives of the zeros of $L_n^1$), at least asymptotically (i.e. for $n$ very large).

Since this lies way outside my area of expertise, does anyone know a reasonably recent reference on such problem? Or maybe the work of someone who dealt with polynomials closely related to $p_n$?
Thank you all in advance.

Comment: The name is "associated Laguerre polynomials". There are no closed form formulas for their zeros. It depends on your needs: do you need numerical approximations ? Mathematica, for example, has implemented these polynomials.

Comment: I used MATLAB to obtain some numerical approximations, but I'd be really interested in some analytical approximations, at least for the biggest zero and large values of $n$. I just found some lower bounds for it in papers from Driver and Jordaan and in another from Lucas, and since all of them are quite recent I fear that's the best I can find.. right?

Comment: Can you give references of these papers ? I imagine that the approach taken is through complex functions theory.

Comment: Maybe, you should describe a little more your problem: you say you are interested by the largest zero of $L_n^1$. Are you interested by an equivalent, or a bracketing of this zero (you mention that these articles provide a lower bound, bu may be you want an upper bound instead ?). A last point: these issues can be as well worked on by converting them into eigenvalue problems.

Comment: the notes from Lucas are the following
[link](https://proceedings.sbmac.org.br/sbmac/article/download/392/398)
and there you can find references also for the other papers I mentioned.
I think in the end what I'd really need is an asymptotic approximation for the smallest (not the largest, sorry about that) zero of $L_n^1$, for large $n$. I actually found something like that in a paper from Gatteschi
[link](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042701005490)
but the limit in there is in terms of the zeros of Bessel functions, which aren't much more treatable analytically.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will try to gve you information about eigenvalues treatment.